# Magento 2: "Forbidden: PHP engine is disable."

Tags: magento2

http://beepitybop.com
http://beepitybop.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js

No images or js is being loaded, but I doubt it's an issue with the symlinks or permissions like the other questions.
The error message is "Forbidden: PHP engine is disable." which is odd because PHP is indeed enabled on the server, and I'm using the default Magento .htaccess file without modifications. Any help will be appreciated.

I don't have access to php.ini. But I can set variables etc in the htaccess file.

```
Technology stack:
Hosting: MDDHosting;
PHP Version: 5.6;
Apache Version: 2.2.31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what was the purpose of these switches, but commenting them out from the .htaccess file under /pub/static/ fixed the problem.

Changed

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>
```

into

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
# php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
# php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>
```